# System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKCanvasView?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to Use Skiasharp on Android, and I get this exception,
what could be the reason?

Code:

```
<skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
               PaintSurface="canvasView_PaintSurface"
               EnableTouchEvents="true" 
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               Touch="OnTouch"/>
```

On C# file

```
private void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender,SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {
            SKSurface sKSurface = args.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = sKSurface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);
            drawPerformerPlatforms.setCanvas(canvas);
            scoreViewerField.runFrame();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting linking to None is a workaround and not a real solution. The problem in your case is that Linker removing the references to Skia classes. You need to preserve the Skia library during the linking process. Please refer to the following article for more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Comment: Another way to avoid this is to use XAML compilation - not only will this preserve the constructor, but will also improve performance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc

Answer (score -1):

Okay I found the answer,
Right click to the Android Project -> Properties -> Android Options

Find linking and set it to none.

[image]

Then Rebuild your project

Comment: This is not good as the app will be huge. Linking is a must for mobile apps.

Comment: Yes but this solved my problem, linking was set to none by default